# How to run Hive Sql query's containing "select count(*)" and "group by" clauses in Hive embedded mode?

Tags: java, sql, hadoop

How can I run this query (1) in Hive embedded mode

```
select product,count(*) as cnt from hive_bigpetstore_etl group by product
```

in the maven console I get a `InvocationTargetException` exception

in the Hive log file I find

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.setColumnTypeList(Utilities.java:2033)
at       org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:351)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushProjectionsAndFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:432)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushProjectionsAndFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:374)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:540)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:412)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

this is a typical row in the input data

`BigPetStore,storeCode_AK,1 russell,baird,Sun Dec 21 11:57:31 PST 1969,20.1,antelope-caller`

the data loads into the table successfully as if I change (1) to (2)

```
`select* from hive_bigpetstore_etl`
```

it returns a correct ResultSet with all the data

I have checked everything is on the class-path, there are no exceptions like class not found, the hive and hadoop home env variables are set and checked with 
    `printenv`
if I run (1) against a standalone Hive/Thrift query (1) runs with no exceptions, I get the exceptions only in embedded mode.

How can I run the 
    `select count(*)` and 
    `group by`

clause's in Hive embedded mode?

Comment: i wonder if its related to character encodings of qoutes or somethign weird like that

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the hive code from branch-0.11 :

```
2023   public static void setColumnTypeList(JobConf jobConf, Operator op) {
2024     RowSchema rowSchema = op.getSchema();
2025 :    if (rowSchema == null) {
2026       return;
2027     }
2028     StringBuilder columnTypes = new StringBuilder();
2029     for (ColumnInfo colInfo : rowSchema.getSignature()) {
2030       if (columnTypes.length() > 0) {
2031         columnTypes.append(",");
2032       }
2033 ----------> columnTypes.append(colInfo.getType().getTypeName());
2034     }
2035     String columnTypesString = columnTypes.toString();
2036     jobConf.set(serdeConstants.LIST_COLUMN_TYPES, columnTypesString);
2037   }
```

Probably the answer is that it for some reason, the colInfo.getType() is returning null.  The question then becomes "why".  Adding some more color to the question (i.e. can you reproduce this error with any count(*) query) might shed some light on that.